# How to get cascading dropdown to work in a grid with Knockout.js

Tags: knockout.js

How do you get cascading dropdown to work with knockout. I don't seem able to access the selection list object so I can refresh the list.

See current code in JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/0byt55pv/1/).

The main issue is with this pseudo code when country dropdown list changes. I would like to be able to use the country id to filter the availableStates collection for the current row.

// Whenever the country changes

```
self.countryId.subscribe(function () {

    // this pseudo code
    alert(countryId);
    var countryId = self.countryId;
    var filtered = availableStates.filter(function (state) {
        return state.countryId == countryId;

    // how do you bind filtered states to available states for the row ?

    });
```

});

Html :

```
<div id="CountryList" style="margin-top:40px; margin-bottom:40px">
    <table id="Countries">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Line No.</th>
                <th>Country</th>
                <th>State</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody data-bind="foreach: stateLines">
            <tr>
                <td data-bind="text: lineNumber"></td>
                <td>
                    <select data-bind="options: $root.availableCountries, value: countryId, optionsValue: 'countryId', optionsText: 'countryName'"></select>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select data-bind="options: $root.availableStates, optionsValue: 'stateId', optionsText: 'stateName', selectedOptions: selectedStates" multiple="true"></select>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Scripts:

```
function StateLine(lineNumber, initialCountry, initialState) {
    var self = this;
    self.lineNumber = lineNumber;
    self.countryId = ko.observable(initialCountry);
    self.selectedStates = ko.observableArray([initialState]);

    // Whenever the category changes, reset the product selection
    self.countryId.subscribe(function () {

        // this pseudo code
        alert(countryId);
        var countryId = self.countryId;
        var filtered = availableStates.filter(function (state) {
            return state.countryId == countryId;

        // how do you bind filtered states to available states for the row ?

        });

    });
}

function StateViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.stateLines = ko.observableArray([]);

    // Get countries
    self.availableCountries = [{
        countryId: "0",
        countryName: "All Countries"
    },{
        countryId: "1",
        countryName: "Brasil"
    }, {
        stateId: "2",
        countryName: "Australia"
    }];

    // Get states
    self.availableStates = [{
        countryId: "1",
        stateId: "1",
        stateName: "Minas Gerais"
    }, {
        countryId: "1",
        stateId: "2",
        stateName: "Espirito Santo"
    }, {
        countryId: "2",
        stateId: "3",
        stateName: "Victoria"
    }, {
        countryId: "2",
        stateId: "4",
        stateName: "New South Wales"
    }];


    self.stateLines.push(new StateLine("Line 1", "0", "1"));
    self.stateLines.push(new StateLine("Line 2", "0", "3"));


} // 

ko.applyBindings(new StateViewModel());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a computed observable and filters the states based on the selected country in each line, then use the filtered array for the options

---

**Javascript**

```
function StateLine(lineNumber, initialCountry, initialState, states) {
    var self = this;
    self.lineNumber = lineNumber;
    self.countryId = ko.observable(initialCountry);
    self.selectedStates = ko.observableArray([initialState]);
    self.filteredStates = ko.computed( function() {
        return states.filter(function (state) {
            var countryId = self.countryId();
            return countryId === undefined || countryId === '0' || state.countryId == countryId;
        });
    });
}

...

self.stateLines.push(new StateLine("Line 1", "0", "1", self.availableStates));
self.stateLines.push(new StateLine("Line 2", "0", "3", self.availableStates));
```

---

**HTML**

```
<td>
  <select data-bind="options: filteredStates, optionsValue: 'stateId', optionsText: 'stateName', selectedOptions: selectedStates" multiple="true"></select>
</td>
```

Comment: Thanks @Robert Slaney. So according to your recommendation I don't need to fiddle with data-bind:options. Leave as data-bind="options : filteredStates. The computed observable will automatically updated according to the value of countryId. Nice. I'll try it now.

Comment: Correct, the computed will automatically recalculate whenever countryId changes

Comment: I tried. It worked. Brilliant! Final JS Fiddle is http://jsfiddle.net/f0gzqgsf/2/

Answer (score 1):

Is this

```
    {
        stateId: "2",
        countryName: "Australia"
    }
```

or

```
    {
        countryId: "2",
        countryName: "Australia"
    }
```

?

Try modifying your subscribe event by passing a parameter like below

```
 self.countryId.subscribe(function (val) {

    // this pseudo code
    alert(val);
    ----- code here ------ 

 });
```

Check the updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/G_sh/0byt55pv/2/)

Let me know if you still see issues.

Comment: Thanks @G_S That was a typo. It should have been: countryId: "2" (second option). I can see I can get countryId through the val variable. But how do I refresh the dropdown list of states based on country value (val)? Do I need to create a property availableStates for each row? Because each row may end up with its own list based on selected country?

Comment: what about having a new observable say filteredStates and setting it whenever your countryId changes?
Also as you mentioned, availableStates for each row would be an ideal solution I guess.

Comment: Thanks @G_S. Your idea about creating the fiteredStates is good and I have implemented it. However I need to update the data-bind with the following logic: if I countryId == 0 then data-bind="options: $root.availableStates otherwise data-bind="options: filteredStates. Can I apply conditions to the data-bind="options mark-up? I want to avoid having to re-generate a back-end query to show all options when countryId is zero.

Comment: your updated fiddle please. Just to use your fiddle to try the case.
You can use data-bind = "options: (countryid == 0)? filteredstates: availablestates" 
Try such conditions and see if they work

Comment: Try if  <td>
                    <select data-bind="options: ($root.countryId == 0)?$root.availableStates : $root.selectedStates , optionsValue: 'stateId', optionsText: 'stateName', selectedOptions: selectedStates" multiple="true"></select>
                </td> logic works